# How to use ansible's user option - ssh_key_bits?

Tags: ansible

Is there any example on how to provide the SSH key for a user using the ssh_key_bits option?

The documentation only specifies the 'password' option and searching for 'ssh_key_bits' only has 5 pages on Google and none of them are useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can try something like this:

```
---
- name: Create User with ssh key bits
  hosts: all
  user: youruser
  sudo: True

  tasks:
    - name: Create user
      user: name=newuser generate_ssh_key=yes ssh_key_bits=4096
```

Comment: I originally thought this field will allow me to specify the ssh keys as a string. I will mark your answer as complete. Do you know of a way to enter SSH key as string?

Comment: @mbdev yes, you can ask it as a different question on SO